# Identify piece of grammar: "Included in this section is a description of a typical system"

Tags: inversion

Here are some phrases:

1. Included in this section is a description of a typical system.
2. Acting upon a body are few forces which cannot be neglected.
3. Connected with this phenomenon are also some other changes.
4. Important as this work is, it does not cover the problem on the whole.

My first question is it English at all? Are these valid English sentences? The sentences look so alien to me.

If yes, what piece of grammar is it? Is it some kind of inversion? When and how do I use it (in everyday life)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first three sentences are what Wikipedia calls [subject–verb inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English).

All of your sentences are valid English sentences. The first three all consist of three parts: a "predicative" part, the main verb, and finally the subject. Normally, they come in the opposite order:

> 1. A description of a typical system / is / included in this section.
> 2. Few forces which cannot be neglected / are / acting upon a body.
> 3. Some other changes / are also / connected with this phenomenon.

The reversal of these three parts suggests that the author is going to talk about the subject some more. Sentence 1 makes me expect that the author will now start giving the description of the typical system; sentence 2 makes me expect that the author will list and describe the forces; and sentence 3 makes me think that the author will explain the other changes that are connected with the phenomenon.

This way of speaking has a bit of an academic sound to it.

---

The fourth sentence is not the same kind as the first three. That sentence consists of the independent clause "it does not cover the problem on the whole", which is modified by the phrase "important as this work is". Here are some ways of rephrasing it:

> - As important as this work is, it does not cover the problem on the whole.
> - Despite the importance of this work, it does not cover the problem on the whole.
> - Although this work is important, it does not cover the problem on the whole.